# Dynamic Arrays in C - Exception thrown

Tags: c, exception, dynamic-arrays

I have started out using dynamic arrays in C, I am getting an exception thrown runtime error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7ECB21A87 in Assignment 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFE7CBC420.

This occurs in the `insertArray()` function, right when I try to store a `char` element in the array variable found in the `struct Array` (see below):

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header3.h"

typedef struct {
    char *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

typedef struct {
    int *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} intArray;

void initArray(int option, Array *a, intArray *b, size_t initialSize) {
    if (option == 1) {
        a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));
        a->used = 0;
        a->size = initialSize;
    }
    else {
        b->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
        b->used = 0;
        b->size = initialSize;
    }
}

void freeArray(int option, Array *a, intArray *b) {
    if (option == 1) {
        free(a->array);
        a->array = NULL;
        a->used = a->size = 0;
    }
    else {
        free(b->array);
        b->array = NULL;
        b->used = b->size = 0;
    }
}

void insertArray(int option, Array *a, intArray *b, char element, int element2) {
    if (option == 1) {
        if (a->used == a->size) {
            a->size *= 2;
            a->array = (char *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char));
        }
        a->array[a->used++] = element; //ERROR HERE
    }
    else {
        if (b->used == b->size) {
            b->size *= 2;
            b->array = (int *)realloc(b->array, b->size * sizeof(int));
        }
        b->array[b->used++] = element2;
    }
}


int main() {
    Array eq, postFx;
    initArray(1, &eq, 0, 2);  // initially 2 elements
    initArray(1, &postFx, 0, 2);
    int i;
    char C;
    printf("Enter character string\n");
    while ((C = getchar()) != EOF)
        insertArray(1, &eq, 0, C, 0);  // automatically resizes as necessary
    //int n = expEvaluate(eq, (eq.used)-1, postFx); //call expEvaluate to process eq
    //printf("\nAnswer: %d", n);
    int chk = getchar(); //readkey (twice)
    freeArray(1, &eq, 0);
    chk = getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get the hang of this, I may be missing something obvious or the problem is bigger than that...either way nay help is appreciated!

Comment: Spend some time learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: well I know how to use a debugger, thanks t the debugger I know exactly where the exception is being thrown, but unfortunately I don't know what is wrong with the code

Comment: 1) `a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));` --> `a->array = (char *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));` 2) `char C;` --> `int C;` 3) need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Apart from the comments above, there seems to be nothing wrong (no crash in MSVC even without the corrections). But was this really a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I wonder what the unecessary `#include "header3.h"` is for.

Comment: The interface to those functions is just awful. Have two sets of functions, one which deals with char arrays, and another that deals with int arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. In initArray: [ int allocate: ( int *) ... ]

   ```
   a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));
   ```

   In insertArray: [ char allocate: ( char *) ... ]

   ```
   a->array = (char *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char));
   ```

It causes problem.

2. Use gdb: GNU Debugger